# How does the server recognize the header compression of different clients in HTTP2

Tags: http2

According to the http2 protocol, the client and the server need to maintain the same static and dynamic dictionary.

For a server, it receives compressed headers from many different clients.

For the header compressed content sent by a client, will it search only in this user's dictionary or all dictionaries?.

If the query is only in the dictionary of a specific client, how does it determine which dictionary the request comes from?

In addition, when does the user's dictionary stored in the server expire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client and server maintain a *per-connection* state that stores the static and dynamic tables that contain the HTTP headers exchanged between the two peers.

There is no concept of "user", just that of connection.

For a client that opens multiple TCP connections, each connection will have a different  dynamic table (the static table is the same for all connections from all clients and it's specified by the HTTP/2 [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7541#appendix-A)).

For all HTTP/2 streams in a connection, the dynamic table is updated by both client and server, so it's always in sync.

Being tied to a TCP connection, the dynamic table is thrown away when the connection is closed.